# I am creating a flutter app which is in link with a woocommerce wordpress site. I want to get a push notification whenever new products are added

Tags: wordpress, flutter, woocommerce

I have tried using firebase notification scheduling like this and its not working.This is the function code I used for sending a custom notification and even this is not working.Is there any errors or is there any alternative ways

```
  void sendNotification()async{
        await Firebase.initializeApp();
        String? fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
        print(fcmToken);
        final FirebaseNotificationScheduler firebaseNotificationScheduler =
        FirebaseNotificationScheduler(
            authenticationKey: 'NTQ5YzA0MjYtZGRjMS00NTliLTllYjYtMDk4YzZhNzliOTgwOktJMDZMTEVpSGNRWjB2Qlk2RXJaazNKclpRZC9IOUc=',
            rapidApiKey: '4e30d77a63msh5302f3fec95c880p1548e5jsn43509ee88c2d');
        final String _payload = {
          "to": fcmToken,
          "notification": {
            "title": "Title of Your Notification",
            "body": "Body of Your Notification"
          },
          "data": {"key_1": "Value for key_1", "key_2": "Value forkey_2"}
        }.toString();
        final DateTime _now = DateTime.now().toUtc();
        final DateTime _dateTimeInUtc = _now.add(const Duration(minutes: 1));
        final response = await firebaseNotificationScheduler.scheduleNotification(
            payload: _payload, dateTimeInUtc: _dateTimeInUtc);
        print("response = $response");
      }
```

Comment: Are you trying to send a push notification to your app from itself? Typically push notifications come from a backend server.

Comment: It was just a test to check weather its working

Comment: In that case the context of woocommerce was probably unnecessary. Your issue in that case is most likely in the receipt of the push notification, not the sending. To be fair though, I have never used the APIs you showed above but it looks mostly correct.

Comment: okay can you suggest a way for push notification to happen  in flutter app when new products are added in the woocommerce

Comment: Absolutely, woocommerce has a webhook for when products are created. Create a webhook that hits an endpoint on your server (you'll need to create a server for this if you don't already have one. If you're unfamiliar with this, then you're probably a little in over your head but not to worry, you'll just need to take some time to learn that new skill). The webhooj request to your server will contain the product info which you can then loop over all your users FCM Ids and send them a new product push notification.

Comment: https://woocommerce.com/document/webhooks/